# Create JSONArray from array of hash

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Array of hash like this

```
[
  {"id":"1","name":"Apple","category":"fruit"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Ball","category":"toy"},
  {"id":"3","name":"Cat","category":"animal"},
  ..
  ..
  {"id":"500","name":"yoyo","category":"toy"},
  ..
]
```

I have a method which accepts `JsonArray`. How can I pass this, so that later I can search a particular type of category like `toy` and return its index?

Since this contains quotes, so I can't even figure out how to directly pass this as a new JsonArray().

Comment: do you need only the first index or an array of indexes which matches the category?

Comment: Can you please show both of those. That would be good to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your JSON string into a `JSONArray` object like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Use the method to find all indexes of specific category

```
public List<Integer> getIndexesOfCategory(JSONArray jsonArray,String category) {
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (category.equals(jsonObject.getString("category"))) {
                indexes.add(i);
            }
        }
        return indexes;
    }
```

Use like this

`List<Integer> indexes = getIndexesOfCategory(jsonArray,"toy")`;

Comment: `error: illegal start of expression
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray({\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Apple\",\"category\":\"fruit\"},...`

Comment: I just can't pass that to the object, even escaped.

Comment: put the string inside double quote JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Apple\",\"category\":\"fruit\"},...");

Comment: Hey. I was able to do this. So this means whatever data I get, it needs to be properly formatted and escaped.